# Generating if-then-else evaluator with Antlr V3 tree parser

Tags: if-statement, antlr, interpreter

I'm writing an interpreter for a simple DSL and wondering how to implement if-then-else evaluator elegantly. I found one example online from antlr.org but it actually used getNodeIndex() from CommonTreeNodeStream, which is protected, so no use. The best I could do was the following:

```
ifblock
@init
{
  int t = 0;
  int f = 0;
}
@after
{
  if(c)
    stream.push(t);
  else
    stream.push(f);
  statements(); // handle the statements in then or else branch
  stream.pop()
}
  : ^(IF c=condition {t = input.mark();}. {f = input.mark();}.)
;
```

This is working, but I am not really satisfied somehow. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate the logic from your tree grammar and create custom node-classes that are responsible for evaluating the input. If you keep it all inside the grammar, it will soon become a big pile of spaghetti, which is hard to maintain, IMO. Especially when you extend the language.

For an example of how to do this, see thie previous Q&A: [if then else conditional evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598975/if-then-else-conditional-evaluation)

Some more related links:

- Scott Stanchfield's excellent ANTLR v3 video blog series: http://javadude.com/articles/antlr3xtut/
- my blog about creating a small dynamic language with ANTLR: http://bkiers.blogspot.com/2011/03/creating-your-own-programming-language.html

Comment: Thanks. I actually wrote my own evaluator using visitor pattern to begin with, but decided to have a go with tree grammar, just to see if it is possible really. I can see the pros and cons more clearly now. A lot of "how to do X properly" is convention rather than hard rules, and I definitely needed to learn that with Antlr :)